# how to fix: float() argument can be string or number, not 'map'

Tags: python, numpy, typeerror

this is my simple code:

I have tried changing some datatype

```
@staticmethod
def load_from_file(filename, size_fit = 50):
    '''
    Loads the signal data from a file.
    filename: indicates the path of the file.
    size_fit: is the final number of sample axes will have.
    It uses linear interpolation to increase or decrease
    the number of samples.
    '''
    #Load the signal data from the file as a list
    #It skips the first and the last line and converts each number into an int
    data_raw = list(map(lambda x: int(x), i.split(" ")[1:-1]) for i in open(filename))
    #Convert the data into floats
    data = np.array(data_raw).astype(float)
    #Standardize the data by scaling it
    data_norm = scale(data)
```

and it throwing an error as:

```
data=np.array(data_raw).astype(float)
float() argument must be 'string' or 'number', not 'map'
```

please help me resolve this issue

Comment: Can you give us an idea of what the file you are trying to open looks like? Also the way I see it, you need to “materialize” the resulting list of maps. You are probably better off breaking down that line (raw_data) into multiple steps for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a list of `map` objects. Try this list comprehension instead:

```
data_raw = [[int(x) for x in i.split()[1:-1]] for i in open(filename)]
```

`split` defaults to splitting on whitespace, so the argument is unnecessary. Also, consider using `with` to properly close your file:

```
with open(filename) as infile:
    data_raw = [[int(x) for x in i.split()[1:-1]] for i in infile]
```

---

On a side note, `numpy` converts strings to numbers for you when you do `astype`, so you could simply do

```
with open(filename) as infile:
    data_raw = [i.split()[1:-1] for i in infile]
```